# Display my two sidebars under content div if mobile phone?

Tags: css, mobile

I have two sidebars on my template and output on desktop computers will look like this:

```
<!--sidebar one--><!--content--><!--sidebar two-->
```

Like in  [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UBb7j/). This looks exactly as i want.

My code for desktop layout:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="sidebar_one">Sidebar one</div>
<div class="content">This is a content</div>
<div class="sidebar_two">Sidebar two</div>
</div>
```

Now on mobile phones I would like to position my two sidebars under my content div.

So the output would look like this:

```
<!--content-->
<!--sidebar one-->
<!--sidebar two-->
```

Like in  [This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8q7rX/)

Now my problem is that I have no idea how to position my sidebars underneath my content without changing my HTML code to this:

```
 <div class="wrapper">
 <div class="content">This is a content</div>
 <div class="sidebar_one">Sidebar one</div>
 <div class="sidebar_two">Sidebar two</div>
 </div>
```

Obviusly this will look great on phones , but on **dektop computers** my sidebars will **still be under** my content div.

So my question is: Is it possible to somehow adjust my first code [First Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UBb7j/) to show my content in the middle, one sidebar on the left and another on the right for **dektop computers**,and for **mobile phones** to show my two sidebars beneath my content?

Comment: Google for "media queries"

Comment: This isn't possible without changing the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heads up! I have solve it:) It looks like **must** use my layout like this:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="content">This is a content</div>
<div class="sidebar_one">Sidebar one</div>
<div class="sidebar_two">Sidebar two</div>
</div>
```

My CSS for mobile devices will look like so:

```
.sidebar_one{
display:block;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:blue;
float:none;
text-align:center;
overflow:hidden;
}

.content{
display:inline-block;/*Notice the inline-block*/
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:red;
float:none;
text-align:center;
}
.sidebar_two{
display:block;
width:100px;
height:100px;
background-color:blue;
float:none;
text-align:center;
}

.wrapper{
display:block;
width:100px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Here is [The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vUTqF/).

My CSS code for desktop computers will look like this:

```
 .sidebar_one{
 display:block;
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 background-color:blue;
 float:right;
 text-align:center;
 overflow:hidden;
 }

 .content{
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:red;
  float:none;
  text-align:center;
  }
  .sidebar_two{
  display:block;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-color:blue;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
  }
  .wrapper{
  display:block;
  width:300px;
  margin:0 auto;
  }
```

Here is [The Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/aDmcf/)

Basically the solution was to add `inline-block` to my content div.
Hope this will help somebody else:)

Answer (score 1):

Use can do this using CSS3 flex. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes.

So in your media queries for your mobile you can shift around elements into any order you want.

So on your parent element you have

```
   display: -webkit-flex;
   display:         flex;
   -webkit-flex-flow: row;
           flex-flow: row;
```

And on your child elements you have for your mobile media query

```
-webkit-order: 1;
        order: 1;
```

And on your child elements you have for your desktop media query

```
-webkit-order: 3;
        order: 3;
```

Only problem you have with this is the browser support. But check for polyfils for non supporting browsers.

I've also added to your fiddle to give you an example http://jsfiddle.net/UBb7j/3/